# R Shiny: How to Export R2D3 plot to png (or jpeg/pdf)

Tags: image, shiny, download, screenshot, networkd3

I’m trying to export an image of a D3 Network map visual which is rendered in R shiny, via a download button. I don’t know much about D3 and have tried various ways of making this work without success. Here is the code I’m trying:

```
## The ui function:
mod_r2d3_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  # Read data
  #library(r2d3)
  #library(jsonlite)
  library(png) # For writePNG function
 
  nodes <- read.csv("inst/app/data/NodesNew.csv")
  edges <- read.csv("inst/app/data/Edges.csv")
  map_list <- list(nodes = nodes,links = edges)
  data <- toJSON(map_list)
  
 tagList(
    
  h1("Network Plot"),
  mainPanel(width="100%",
            d3Output(ns("d3Plot"), width = "100%", height = "800px"),
            downloadButton(ns("download"),label="Download the plot")
            )
   
  ) #End of tagList
}
```

```
##And the server function:
mod_r2d3_server <- function(id){
  moduleServer( id, function(input, output, session){
    ns <- session$ns
 
    nodes <- read.csv("inst/app/data/NodesNew.csv")
    edges <- read.csv("inst/app/data/Edges.csv")
    map_list <- list(nodes = nodes,links = edges)
    data <- toJSON(map_list)
    
    #Send that json from the session to our javascript
    session$sendCustomMessage(type="jsondata",data)
    
    output$d3Plot<-renderD3({
      data<-data
      vis<-r2d3(css="inst/app/data/net.css", data=data, script = "inst/app/www/net.js", d3_version = "4",sizingPolicy(padding = 0, browser.fill = TRUE,viewer.fill=TRUE))
    
    })

    output$download<- downloadHandler(
      #Specify the file name
      filename = function(){"thename.png"},
        content = function(file) {
          #open the download
          #create/ write the plot
          #close dowload
          png(file)
          print(vis)
          dev.off()
      } #end of content
    ) #end of downloadHandler

})
}
```

Please note this is part of a golem framework and is in a shiny dashboard layout if that helps add context.
I would be grateful for any tips/solutions.

I have also tried shinyscreenshot but though it creates a button, no screenshot is taken.

```
mod_r2d3_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  # Read data
 
  
  #library(r2d3)
  #library(jsonlite)
  library(png) # For writePNG function
  library(js)
  library(shinyscreenshot)
  #library('highcharter')
  
  #install.packages("remotes")
  #remotes::install_github("daattali/shinyscreenshot")
  
  
  
  nodes <- read.csv("inst/app/data/NodesNew.csv")
  edges <- read.csv("inst/app/data/Edges.csv")
  map_list <- list(nodes = nodes,links = edges)
  data <- toJSON(map_list)
  

  tagList(
    
  h1("Network Plot"),

  mainPanel(width="100%",
            actionButton("go", "Capture page"),
            #screenshotButton(id="d3Plot", label = 'Download Png', filename = 'screenshot'),
            d3Output(ns("d3Plot"), width = "100%", height = "800px"),
            )
   
  ) #End of tagList
}


mod_r2d3_server <- function(id){
  moduleServer( id, function(input, output, session){
    ns <- session$ns
 
    nodes <- read.csv("inst/app/data/NodesNew.csv")
    edges <- read.csv("inst/app/data/Edges.csv")
    map_list <- list(nodes = nodes,links = edges)
    data <- toJSON(map_list)
    
    #Send that json from the session to our javascript
    session$sendCustomMessage(type="jsondata",data)
    
    output$d3Plot<-renderD3({
      data<-data
      r2d3(css="inst/app/data/net.css", data=data, script = "inst/app/www/net.js", d3_version = "4",sizingPolicy(padding = 0, browser.fill = TRUE,viewer.fill=TRUE))
    
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$go, {
        screenshot(id='d3Plot')
      
    })
   })
}
```

I managed to get a version working that took a screenshot as soon as the app was opened, but that's not what I needed. Need it to take a screenshot when button is pressed. But it suggests I do have the right functionality/ packages to get it working...

Update: Since trying out the capture package for this I have found that I need to work with an older version of R for a client, which doesn't support some of the newer packages like capture or snapper. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Try the capture package https://github.com/dreamRs/capture

Comment: Thanks the capture package worked really well!

Comment: One follow up question, I can't get the capture_pdf() version to work...does this require an extra package or different code to capture()?